# Sync directive data with factory value updated by an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

I've got two simple directives, let's call them `blue` and `red`. What I need is for them to work in such a way that when I click the button in the `red` directive, the value in `blue` gets automatically updated. And vice versa.

It's fairly simple to do using a factory... that is until the function updating data becomes an $http call which changes data only after it has finished successfully.

I've got a working pluker without $http here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Dyy3AEu68OwjRqLahXMX?p=preview

And here's my attempt with $http:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FD2538Ji4NbvY5wrjYgz?p=preview

Am I missing something or it's just not the way to do it? I understand that it can be done using $broadcast but it just seems like an overkill to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/rrowocPucUFAN6Ii1COf?p=preview

You were using 'data' both in the factory, and as a variable name within the success callback.

This is the offending section:

```
myFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function myFactory($http) {

    var data = {};

    data.blueData = 0;
    data.redData = 0;

    data.changeBlueData = function () {
        $http.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').
            success(function(response, status, headers, config) {  // Changed "data" to "response";
                data.blueData++;
            });
    };

    data.changeRedData = function () {
        $http.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').
            success(function(response, status, headers, config) {  // Changed "data" to "response"
                data.redData++;
            });
    };

    return data;
}
```

Response is a clearer variable name, and a standard name for a return from AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with these lines:

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
```

You already have a data variable, and the success function parameter has the same name. you should change it to something like:

```
success(function(ajaxData, status, headers, config) {
```